# cambiar imagen actual por una miniatura generada de un video

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente código que me genera una miniatura de un video, sólo que al momento de mostrarla la posiciona debajo del input y lo que deseo es cambiarla por la imagen actual que se muestra al principio.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
const Portada = styled.img`
  background-color: silver;
  width: 120%;
`;
class SeleccionarVideo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      profileImg:
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/15/17/18/vector-video-player-941434_960_720.png",
    };
  }

  videoHandler = (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = () => {
      var blob = new Blob([reader.result], { type: file.type });
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var video = document.createElement("video");
      var timeupdate = function () {
        if (snapImage()) {
          video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", timeupdate);
          video.pause();
        }
      };
      video.addEventListener("loadeddata", function () {
        if (snapImage()) {
          video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", timeupdate);
        }
      });
      var snapImage = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvas
          .getContext("2d")
          .drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var image = canvas.toDataURL();
        var success = image.length > 100000;
        if (success) {
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = image;
          document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].appendChild(img);
          URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
        return success;
      };
      video.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeupdate);
      video.preload = "metadata";
      video.src = url;
      // Load video in Safari / IE11
      video.muted = true;
      video.playsInline = true;
      video.play();
    };
    this.setState({ profileImg: reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file) });
  };
  render() {
    const { profileImg } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="img-holder">
            <Portada src={profileImg} alt="" id="img" className="img" />
          </div>
          <input type="file" accept="video/*" onChange={this.videoHandler} />
        </div>
        <div></div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default SeleccionarVideo;
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como obtener una imagen de video en html - JS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386330/como-obtener-una-imagen-de-video-en-html-js)